# PC crash, EXT4-fs error --ext4_find_entry inode reading directory iblock 0

Tags: log, ext4, systemd-journald

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

DISK: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB

My pc suddenly stopped working. It stops responding to commands, the icons (especially the ones to manage windows) disappear and are replaced by what I think is a temporary icon. If I move to another tty, I see that so many errors are printed:

```
"EXT4-fs error (device sda2): --ext4_find_entry inode comm gmain
 reading directory iblock 0"
```

I can't take screens because the pc doesn't work anymore and all I can do is do a forced shutdown by holding down the power button. I've already done disk checks to make sure it was healthy and I've already reinstalled the operating system. I don't know what to try anymore.

I don't know where to find these errors in the logs so I can't copy paste them, if anyone knows I will update the question

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; thus can only be generic, but given the *fs* error, have you checked hardware health staring with drive sda?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) PSU etc (*as even good components misbehave if fed poor power*) etc. If you need to power down (and can't clean shutdown using SysRq commands) that highlights hardware issues in my opinion. Have you booted *live* and performed *file-system* checks?  though I'd check hardware first; as if you have hardware issues you'll not help file-recovery by doing *fs* checks/fixes first...

Comment: I don't know what a SysRq command is but when it happens I can't do anything anymore so I guess I can't do it. I had done hardware checks but found no problem, I should try again right now

Comment: SysRq is a key on an IBM compatible keyboard (*though it was written on the front of the key, and with modern ultra-slim keyboards it isn't always printed on key, but key is there though may require a Fn key also to be used*). It's how you give commands to the Linux kernel directly bypassing any stuck GUI or crashed UI that thus can't accept input... As long as kernel hasn't panic'd it'll respond. If unsure, pull out phone & search "magic sysrq" and wikipedia page is often shown.. It only requires a real keyboard to be connected (*and not onscreen keyboard so can't use it on android phones!*)

Comment: Thank you, I will look about this sysrq and try it next time. In the meantime, I did a live boot from a usb with ubuntu 22.04 and fsck on /dev/sda2 :
`/dev/sda2: clean, 550008/61022208 files, 114976893/244059136 blocks`

Comment: This morning it happened again, I was updating steam, it almost seems to happen when a lot of data is written to the disk. I just tried sysrq and managed to reboot the pc but on reboot I got a no boot device error. shutting down with the button solved it

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that error before in relation to APST (Autonomous Power State Transition)

> APST allows a host to configure the controller to automatically transition between power states without software intervention when specific conditions are met. For example, the transition power state is triggered when a controller is idle for a particular time. Furthermore, a non-operational power state can automatically transition to another non-operational power state.

Two things to try:

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add  `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0` behind `quit`
and then do

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

See if that fixes it. If not do the same using `pcie_aspm=off`.

Comment: thanks, I'll try and if in the next few days it doesn't happen again I'll mark the answer as correct

Comment: this morning it happened again, pc crashed, I switched tty and the error was failed to rotate /var/log/journal: read-only filesystem. I tried both of the options you gave me

Answer (score -1):

This error happens especially when your system can't read or write to your disks correctly or efficiently. This could be because your disk is held loosely, damaged, or ports needs some cleaning.

It could also happen if you're located where there is a strong electromagnetic fields or anything else that can disturb the operations of your disks.

Anyway, this problem is often not a issue until the system requires to do millions of abrupt reads or write operations. For example, in power state transition, i.e., if the system is idle, waking the system up will require lots of quick writes and reads, which will definitely crash the pc if it can't handle the requests properly.

So, check your disks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).